# How to send raw JSON data to PHP server from android?

Tags: php, android, json, gson

I want to send some data to php from android and do some operation in php. My problem is i can't send data via to my php file. I want to send the rawJson to php.
Please help me how can i do that. I have tried this way..

**Register Button**

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String phone = inputPhone.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            String passwordrepeat = inputPasswordRepeat.getText().toString();
            if (checkdata(name, phone, email, password, passwordrepeat))
            {
                RegistroSolicitud oUsuario = new RegiterRequest();
                oUser.setName(name);
                oUser.setEmail(email);
                oUser.setPhone(phone);
                oUser.setPassword(password);
                Register(gson.toJson(oUser));
            }
        }
    });
```

**Register Method**

```
private void Register(String rawJson) {
    serviceAsyncService = new AsyncService(this, MyService.RegisterWebService, rawJson);
    servicioAsyncService.setOnCompleteListener(new AsyncTaskListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskDownloadedFinished(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            try {
                int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(result.get("StatusCode").toString());
                if (statusCode == 0) {
                    registerResult = gson.fromJson(result.get("Result").toString(), RegisterResult.class);
                    if ((!registerResult.isError()) && registerResult.getData() != null) {
                        userController.deleteAll();
                        userController.saveUser(registerResult.getData());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception error) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskUpdate(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskComplete(HashMap<String, Object> result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskCancelled(HashMap<String, Object> result) {

        }
    });
    servicioAsyncService.execute();
}
```

**AsyncService.java**

```
public class ServicioAsyncService extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap<String, Object>> {
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Act";

private AsyncTaskListener asyncTaskListener;
private HashMap<String, Object> resultados;
private Context context;
private String servicioURL;
private String rawJson;


public ServicioAsyncService(Context prContext, String prUrl, String prRawJson) {
    this.context = prContext;
    this.servicioURL = prUrl;
    this.rawJson = prRawJson;
    resultados = new HashMap<String, Object>();

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    asyncTaskListener.onTaskStart();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(String... params) {

    disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary();
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        // create connection
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        URL urlToRequest = new URL(servicioURL);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlToRequest.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        if(rawJson != null) {
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            osw.write(rawJson);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }

        // handle issues
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            // handle unauthorized (if service requires user login)
        } else if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // handle any other errors, like 404, 500,..
            resultados.put("IsValid", false);
            resultados.put("StatusCode", statusCode);
            resultados.put("Resultado", null);
            return resultados;
        }

        // create JSON object from content
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                urlConnection.getInputStream());
        String resultado = getResponseText(in);
        resultados.put("IsValid", true);
        resultados.put("StatusCode",0);
        resultados.put("Resultado", resultado);
        onTaskDownloadedFinished(resultados);
        return resultados;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // URL is invalid
        resultados.put("IsValid", false);
        resultados.put("Resultado", null);
        resultados.put("StatusCode", 300);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // data retrieval or connection timed out
        resultados.put("IsValid", false);
        resultados.put("Resultado", null);
        resultados.put("StatusCode", 300);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        resultados.put("IsValid", false);
        resultados.put("Resultado", null);
        resultados.put("StatusCode", 300);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return resultados;
}

private static void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
    // see HttpURLConnection API doc
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK)
            < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }
}

private static String getResponseText(InputStream inStream) {
    String resultado = new Scanner(inStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, resultado);
    return resultado;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
    asyncTaskListener.onTaskComplete(result);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress[0]);
    asyncTaskListener.onTaskUpdate(progress[0]);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCancelled(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
    asyncTaskListener.onTaskCancelled(null);
    super.onCancelled(result);
}

public void setOnCompleteListener(AsyncTaskListener asyncTaskListener) {
    this.asyncTaskListener = asyncTaskListener;
}

private void onTaskDownloadedFinished(HashMap<String, Object> result){
    asyncTaskListener.onTaskDownloadedFinished(result);
}
}
```

**Service.php**

```
<?php



$json = $_REQUEST["rawJson"];
$user = json_decode($json);
$name = $user->Name;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_users");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "fam_monitor_file(fam, filename)d to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
      //Insert in db
}

?>
```

Comment: in php json_encode($data) function which convert array to json format after that echo your json data echo json_encode($data);

Comment: i want to send a rowJson to php from android, 
My question is, how do I get the rawJson in php

Comment: use this at the top of php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $user = (array) json_decode($postdata);

Comment: resolved, thank you Shree!